# splitActionBarWhenNarrow not working in Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, splitactionbar

I know that there are many people had this question. I try to search and study but I can not. I want have a top and bottom action bar in my app. I used `splitActionBarWhenNarrow` but it didn't work. I am using Galaxy S3 to test app.

Here is my code: File `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
            android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />        
    </activity>
</application>
```

File MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Please help me to solve it. I tried many time.

Thanks you